# What happen if KNN has k=1 and there are 2 nearest classes with the same distance

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour, ties, voting-system

What happen if KNN has k=1 and there are 2 nearest classes with the same distance?
as fare as I know, If k is even number and have equal classes number it will random class for the answer.
But what about k equal 1 will it also random the classes too?

BTW, what if k = 2 but class "good" have distance equal 2 and class "bad" have distance equal 3. is the answer is "good"? or we pick on at random?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [tie-breaking rules](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/breaking-ties-k-nn-classification-nicholas-pylypiw), the heuristics that make the decision. The most common approach is to just pick one at random.

Comment: Thank you. BTW, what if k = 2 but class "good" have distance equal 2 and class "bad" have distance equal 3. is the answer is "good"? or we pick on at random?

Comment: It depends on your decision rules. One approach could be to pick at random. Another could be to weight inverse to distance, so since the “good” point is closer, the point is more likely to be “good”.